# Software for blind chess?

Tags: software, blindfold-chess

I recently found a neat feature of Apple's Chess program that allows the player to speak moves, and the computer to speak back moves which makes blind chess very simple and comfortable.

There are a few quirks with the program though. I sometimes stutter when I speak and the Chess program too often interprets what I say as "Undo" with no auditory indication that it undoed. This leads to desyncs between the game the computer's playing and the game in my head.

Is there a program with similar speech-to-move functionality except more refined? I'm okay with the limited commands I can give but I can't deal with my games taking back moves with no indication I can observe. Note: Speaking my moves is very important because I'd like to lie down and relax without keeping my hands on the keyboard to type in moves.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the program, add which languages it supports for voice recognition and add whether it speaks back to you the moves it makes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a website dedicated to playing chess by voice command:
https://sites.google.com/site/chesswithvoice/

I didn't check it but apparently it gives instructions on using the Interfaces Arena or Fritz using voice command.

Maybe you'll find some interesting possibilities there.

Comment: @ BlindKungFuMaster, the link you provided does not work. Please change it so others don't find it unhelpful.

Answer (score 0):

Nimzo Guernica 2.2.1, an old DOS program published in 1993, had extensions for physically blind people including voice output. But I have no idea if it is operable on today's hardware and I assume it lacked speech recognition. But as you can train keyboard commands to a speech recognition program, you can run every chess program that allows for them with it.

Comment: The program I'm looking for has voice-to-move functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your title your question is not clear with regard to voice command for the blind. But Braille chess has been available for years. There are a number of groups specifically for this. [The Braille Chess Association of Ireland](http://www.iol.ie/~vics/bcai/)

I am sure there are many US based as well.

The chess.com web site has a good article about the history of Blind Chess...
[history of blind chess playing](http://www.chess.com/blog/batgirl/blind-ambition)

I am sure there is further info on their site about software.

Comment: I thought the question was pretty clearly about blindfold chess.

Comment: I'd be okay with 1 link to a specific program as an answer. I.e. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_(OS_X). I read through those two articles and neither of them mention any computer program (only a random Irish dude and some OTB blind chess procedures).

Comment: You must have missed the MANY links embedded throughout the article about software, here are a few...http://www.arkangles.com/kchess/blind.html   there are two links here   http://www.arkangles.com/kchess/advance.html  and another... https://sites.google.com/a/aicfb.in/aicfb/talk-64

Comment: I think this is the Windows 7 version....http://k-chess-elite.en.softonic.com/?ab=0

Comment: Ok not MANY links, but there were a few.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many links there are. None of them work. AICFB looked very promising but the download is broken, and the other programs you listed don't have speech-to-move functionality.

Comment: Its not broken I just downloaded it. Try this link.http://k-chess-elite.en.softonic.com/download#downloading look for the green bar at the top that says "if your download does not start click here"  I don't why you don't think they work, I was able to access all of them. good luck, I hope that helps.